# Calculate differences between rows while grouping with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

I have a postgresql table containing movements of different items (models) between warehouses.

For example, the following record means that 5 units of model 1 have been sent form warehouse 1 to 2:

```
source target model units
------ ------ ----- -----
     1      2     1     5
```

I am trying to build a SQL query to obtain the difference between units sent and received, grouped by models.  Again with an example:

```
source target model units
------ ------ ----- -----
     1      2     1     5  -- 5 sent from 1 to 2
     1      2     2     1
     2      1     1     2  -- 2 sent from 2 to 1
     2      1     1     1  -- 1 more sent from 2 to 1
```

The result should be:

```
source target model diff
------ ------ ----- ----
     1      2     1    2   -- 5 sent minus 3 received
     1      2     2    1
```

I wonder if this is possible **with a single SQL query**.

Here is the table creation script and some data, just in case anyone wants to try it:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE movements
(
    source  INTEGER,
    target  INTEGER,
    model   INTEGER,
    units   INTEGER
);

insert into movements values (1,2,1,5);
insert into movements values (1,2,2,1);
insert into movements values (2,1,1,2);
insert into movements values (2,1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need? I don't have an Oracle DB to test against so I hope the rules on Grouping expressions are the same as for MS SQL Server

```
SELECT     
 CASE WHEN source < target THEN source ELSE target END AS source,
 CASE WHEN source < target THEN target ELSE source END AS target,
 SUM(CASE WHEN source < target THEN units ELSE -units END) AS Diff, 
    model
FROM  movements
GROUP BY
 CASE WHEN source < target THEN source ELSE target END,
 CASE WHEN source < target THEN target ELSE source END,
    model
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with two subselects which sum the movements in each direction, and then union and sum the results of those two subqueries:

```
SELECT source, target, model, SUM(units)
FROM (
    SELECT source, target, model, SUM(units) AS units
    FROM movements
    WHERE source < target
    GROUP BY source, target, model
    UNION ALL
    SELECT target, source, model, SUM(-units) AS units
    FROM movements
    WHERE source > target
    GROUP BY source, target, model
) T1
GROUP BY source, target, model
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try it.  How does your query compare to the query provided by @Martin Smith, that avoids the use of "UNION ALL" (uses some CASE clauses instead) ?

Comment: @Guido: His answer scans the table only once, mine scans it twice. How many rows do you have? Is performance an issue? I would claim that my suggestion is more clear / readable, but thats my own opinion and is subjective.

Comment: I've scrubbed my code formatting up a bit to make it marginally more aesthetic but I have to agree the 5 repeating CASE statements detract from readability. I would claim that mine is perhaps more in the spirit of the "single SQL query" part of the question though by virtue of only containing 1 "SELECT" :-)

Comment: I mark Martin's answer as valid, as it is easier to add additional filters in his query.  The table is quite big as well.  Thank you both.